# Using SSIS denormalize the data from xml file and load into sql server

Tags: sql, xml, ssis

I am new to SSIS, I am trying to load data from XML file into SQL server table. I have created the project and can transform and load data into table, but with one issue, below is sample of XML data

```
<EventLocationInfo>
                <Facility>NY 31</Facility>
                <Direction>eastbound</Direction>
                <City>Cicero</City>
                <County>Onondaga</County>
                <State>NY</State>
            <LocationDetails>
                        <LocationItem>
                            <Intersections>
                                    <PrimaryLoc>I-81</PrimaryLoc>
                                    <Article>area of</Article>
                            </Intersections>
                        </LocationItem>     
                        <LocationItem>
                            <PointCoordinates Datum="NAD83">
                                <Lat>43.1755981445313</Lat>
                                <Lon>-76.1159973144531</Lon>
                            </PointCoordinates>
                        </LocationItem>
                        <LocationItem>
                            <AssociatedCities>
                                    <PrimaryCity>Cicero</PrimaryCity>
                                    <Article>area of</Article>
                            </AssociatedCities>
                        </LocationItem>
            </LocationDetails>
        </EventLocationInfo>
```

The result I am getting is like this

[image]

Is it possible to generate only one row instead of getting three different rows, if possible what Data Flow Transformation tool i can use to get this result.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Brijesh

Comment: What about `Script Task`?

Comment: Can you run your XML through an XML task that does the de-normalization before you feed it into the Data Flow Task?

Comment: Thanks for the response guys,I will check Script Task and  XML task and see if this resolves my issue